# How to add a url behind the string which was the user typed to post on the social network by using ShareKit?

Tags: ios, url, sharekit

I think I may need to edit the code of the sending action of each service . But I don't know the details about it , thank .

Comment: Yes , the result I want is that the hyperlink will be shown on the social network website only . After the user finish his entering of the content , it will be added atomically behind the content . The propose of that is to make sure the url will be shown , and the user cannot edit the hyperlink (/url)

Comment: I hope you are not talking about [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

Comment: Of course not , I just want to put a link behind the users' text when they shared something by ShareKit . And the link will be shown , such as posting on the Facebook wall . The url address just link to the website of the app only